# Filenot found exception in Android Emulator and Android version < 3.0

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, android-networking

I have the following code where I am trying to make a call to the webservice in order to get the data onto my android application.

```
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            Log.i("URL", urls[0].toString());
            String data=AppData.getKeyId();
            System.out.println("http key: "+data);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("encryptText", data);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(50000);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + Data.getInstance().getSessionId());
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("Resp Code"+ ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode());
            if (((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode() == 200) return getStringFromInputStream(is);
```

The above code gives me file not found exception when i try to run the application in android emulator and android versions < 3.0 but works just fine in version 3 and above( tested it in 3, 4.0 and 4.4). The internet permission are also set in android manifest. What might be the possible problem?

Here is my logcat

```
> 01-16 02:17:51.684: W/System.err(336): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> http://192.168.1.2:7029/FieldForceAutomation/service/PreSalesResource/Customer/Save?custName=newcustomer
> &custProf=Nil&addrs=avadi road
> &addline1=&addline2=&cityId=2&areaId=2&pincode=000000&resno=0&offno=00000000&mobno=5555555589&emailid=raj@gmail.com&secName=&profWa=&altEmail=None&dcr_no=2001640928&comments=&hasPC=0&serviceProviderId=1&bandwidth=0&status=2&calltypeId=3&custTypeId=1&followUpDate=00210706&createDate=20140116&created_time=02:15:28&chkFeasible=false&userName=sr@act.com
> 01-16 02:17:51.694: W/System.err(336):    at
> org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
> 01-16 02:17:51.704: W/System.err(336):    at
> com.act.Util.HttpReq$Req.doInBackground(HttpReq.java:74) 01-16
> 02:17:51.704: W/System.err(336):  at
> com.act.Util.HttpReq$Req.doInBackground(HttpReq.java:1) 01-16
> 02:17:51.704: W/System.err(336):  at
> android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 01-16 02:17:51.714:
> W/System.err(336):    at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
> 01-16 02:17:51.723: W/System.err(336):    at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 01-16
> 02:17:51.723: W/System.err(336):  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
> 01-16 02:17:51.723: W/System.err(336):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
> 01-16 02:17:51.733: W/System.err(336):    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 01-16 02:17:51.814:
> D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM 01-16 02:17:51.814:
> W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0x40015560) 01-16 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main 01-16 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 01-16 02:17:51.844:
> E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> com.act.PreSalesFormActivity$5$2.onClick(PreSalesFormActivity.java:1394)
> 01-16 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 01-16 02:17:51.844:
> E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 01-16 02:17:51.844:
> E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 01-16
> 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-16
> 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-16 02:17:51.844:
> E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 01-16
> 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-16
> 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 01-16 02:17:51.844:
> E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 01-16 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 01-16
> 02:17:51.844: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the http response code you receive? You could try reading the Error Stream for possible errors related to the http connection. Just for the info, [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) will throw a FileNotFoundException for 400 or above.

Comment: I resolved the error. Turned out to be some encoding problem with URL. Thank you.